# Entity Design in C# EF - linking only one table at a time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

This is a difficult question to formulate, so I'll do my best. I'm trying to come up with the most sensible DB design to represent the following scenario:

We have an object represented by *Entity A* which has certain dimensions. The issue is, depending on the type of object (which is a property of *Entity A*) the dimensions are different and have different designations.

For argument sake let's say in our web application a user wants to create a new object and they can choose either a cylinder or a box. The cylinder will have 2required dimensions (diameter and length), the box will have 3 (height, width, depth).

Initial idea was to have two separate entities *CylinderDimensions* and *BoxDimensions* which are linked to *Entity A* through FK constraint; the Id of *Entity A* stored as part of the Dimension entities. But how would this work with the EF in C#? Would we need two separate properties set up in the model and ensure only one of them actually has value at any time?

Comment: Is inheritance and polymorphism what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: What are the actual requirements? In some cases it might be best to only store properties that needs to be searchable as columns, and the actual object representation as a serialized blob. Serialization libraries tend to have good support for polymorphism, and that way you may not need to update the schema for each type of shape.